# C# database Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition

Tags: c#, sql-server

Have just started working with C# and sql and have been trying to use a database to store information, but not 100% on the syntax of it all and have been piecing it together, but have not been able to get past this error, any help would be appreciated, it is probably only something simple i have looked over.

here is the C# code i am using to try and access the database

```
SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=""F:\Bar admin\Bar admin\Database.mdf"";Integrated Security=True");
SqlCommand DatabaseNew = new SqlCommand("insert into Events Values(@Name, @Date, @Price, @Tickets, @Descrip)");
myConnection.Open();
// adds the event information to the database
DatabaseNew.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", TxtName.Text);
DatabaseNew.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", dateTimePicker1.Value);
DatabaseNew.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Price", TxtName.Text);
DatabaseNew.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Tickets",    Convert.ToInt16(TxtTicketNum.Text));
DatabaseNew.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Descrip", TxtDesc.Text);

DatabaseNew.Connection = myConnection;
int n = DatabaseNew.ExecuteNonQuery();
if (n>0)
{
  MessageBox.Show("Event" + TxtName.Text + "Added");
}
myConnection.Close();
```

and the sql code

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Events] (
  [Id]          INT        NOT NULL,
  [Name]        NCHAR (10) NULL,
  [Date]        DATETIME NULL,
  [Price]       NCHAR(10) NULL,
  [Tickets]     INT NULL,
  [TicketsSold] INT NULL,
  [Descrip]        NVARCHAR(50) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

Again any help would be much apreaciated, thank you.

Comment: Why you have tagged `mysql`, you are using classes for SQL Server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is expecting all fields with exact order. So Id and TicketsSold are missing and causing error. You should change to:

```
    SqlCommand DatabaseNew = new SqlCommand("insert into Events
 (Name,Date,Price,Tickets,Decrip) Values(@Name, @Date, @Price, @Tickets, @Descrip)");
```

Comment: Thank you, so this syntax used a few places but was sure why, now i understand.

Answer (score 3):

You are not passing `ID` and it doesn't appear that your ID is set to Auto increment.

Comment: Cheers, yeah i think i did that before but forgot to update it, thanks for spotting it.